# What's the difference between x.iloc[1]['x'] and x['x'].iloc[1]

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I cannot change the value of np.nan to 16 with x.iloc[1]['x']=16, but I can change it with x['x'].iloc[1]=16. Why? and what's the difference between these two expressions?

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, np.nan, 3], 'y': [3, 4, 5]})

x.iloc[1]['x']=16

print(x.iloc[1]['x'])

nan
```

---

```
x['x'].iloc[1]=16

print(x.iloc[1]['x'])

16.0
```

Comment: They are both cases of chained indexing and neither of them is guaranteed to work. In your case, selecting a column first gives you a view so your assignment is successful but you shouldn't rely on that. Either do `x.loc[x.index[1], 'x'] = 16` or `x.iloc[1, x.columns.get_loc('x')] = 16`

Comment: @ayhan hi, would you mind clarifying further on why chained indexing is not guaranteed to work?

Comment: Why does assignment fail when using chained indexing? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid chained indexing

As noted in the comments, neither of your alternatives are guaranteed to work. The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) explain the reasoning and rationale.

The fact one works and the other doesn't isn't worthy of investigation, as these are implementation details liable to change.

For scalars, you should use `iat` to set values *by integer position* or `at`*by label*.

#### [`iat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) for scalar setting by integer position

```
x.iat[1, x.columns.get_loc('x')] = 16
```

#### [`at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) for scalar setting by label

```
x.at[x.index[1], 'x'] = 16
```

Where your dataframe index is a regular `pd.RangeIndex`, the last assignment can be simplified:

```
x.at[1, 'x'] = 16
```

Comment: Does chained indexing fail only when it involves dataframes with multiindex columns though?

Comment: @kerwei, Not sure and, most importantly, *not relevant*. If it works, it's an *implementation detail* which should *not* be relied upon.

Comment: So what I need to do is to test it out for both methods and see which one works. Thank you!

Comment: @UpcaseM, Well, not really.. *both* the options I describe work. And both will always work. Which you choose depends on preference, or possibly what's convenient for your logic/data.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on Stackoverflow
the answer provided in comment is clear and sufficient.

iloc is a great tool, I would add if you want to use it the way you want, you have to pass first the column on which you want to select the row. Example with a loop over a dataframe to change a value:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = {'col1': [1, 2,'np.nan',4,5], 'col2': ['A','B','C','D','E']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

     col1 col2
0       1    A
1       2    B
2  np.nan    C
3       4    D
4       5    E


for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['col1'].iloc[i] == "np.nan":
            df['col1'].iloc[i] = 16 

print(df)
   col1 col2
0     1    A
1     2    B
2    16    C
3     4    D
4     5    E
```